# Sharing Layout with Portable Area in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My application is designed to use portable area to modules of functionalities. But each of these modules has to use the _LayoutBase from the root project. The Layout of the these modules are set with 
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
The css and scripts referenced in _LayoutBase are not loaded when accessing

http:/localhost/RootWeb/module1/account/login

Any idea how do I resolve this. Any help is greatly appreciated

- George

Answer (score 2):

I have just dealt with this type of issue, here was our workaround:

Open _ViewStart.cshtml for your module and change to this:

```
@{
    this.Layout = "~/Areas/<YourModuleName>/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
```

Open _Layout.cshtml for your module and update this (sets it to the root application's _Layout):

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Also, you have a couple options regarding the CSS/Scripts issues:

1. Update all references to the said area; "~/Content/style.css" ==> "/AreaName/Content/style.css" (and the same for the JS files)
2. Add the CSS/JS to the root bundle config and layouts, ensuring it gets loaded from there.  Remember to move all other required assets up to the root as well or you will be missing images and the like.